# Linker command failed (clang-13)

Tags: macos, command-line, development

I'm installing [this software](https://github.com/delphes/delphes) for my research, but I'm getting this macOS-related error (macOS Monterey 12.3.1) and I'm not quite sure if it is something I can handle myself or if I should contact the support team:

```
>> Building libDelphesNoFastJet.dylib
ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libDelphesNoFastJet.dylib] Error 1
```

It’s mostly tcl code with some c++ and I’m not sure how to decompose this error to dig deeper at a quick fix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, presumably *something* is setting `-mmacosx-version-min` to 10.4 or earlier, so you might start by searching for that flag! Perhaps the build system expects the major version to start with `10.X` and is getting confused?

Comment: Thanks, @Wowfunhappy. I took a look at the `Makefile` and I found these lines, but I don't really understand them: `ifneq ($(subst $(MACOSX_MINOR),,1234),1234)
ifeq ($(MACOSX_MINOR),4)
 @ln -sf $@ $(subst .$(DllSuf),.so,$@)
endif endif` Any guidance?

Comment: You might just take out the #ifdefs so the code always runs and comment out the alternative (or vice-versa). You also may have more luck on stack overflow.

Comment: Considering this bug https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/delphes/ticket/1481 I think you need to discuiss this with the developers as macOS seems not to be supported well. I suspect they have assumed macOS is always 10.x so only look at MACOS_MINOR

Comment: Thanks, @mmmmmm. That seems to be the problem since one of the bin files explicitly has the line `MACOSXTARGET := 10.$(MACOSX_MINOR)` so I contacted the developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a bug in the software's Makefile.

It assumes that macOS is always of the form 10.x which it was for 20 years.

The bad lines include

```
MACOSXTARGET := 10.$(MACOSX_MINOR)
```

```
ifneq ($(subst $(MACOSX_MINOR),,1234),1234) 
ifeq ($(MACOSX_MINOR),4)    @ln -sf $@ $(subst.$(DllSuf),.so,$@) 
endif 
endif
```

There is a similar [bug](https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/delphes/ticket/1481) reported 15 months ago after macOs 11.0 came out